# Testers says __RequestVerificationToken_Lw__ cookies should be expired on logout?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-4, razor-2

I am working on a MVC 4 web site, tester has informed me on Logout .ASPXAUTH cookies expired automatically but **RequestVerificationToken_Lw** cookies do not expires.

I am not sure is **RequestVerificationToken_Lw** suppose to expire on logout ? On logout user is returned to logon page which do not have Html.AntiForgeryToken() used in it. Any guidline please how I can set **RequestVerificationToken_Lw** to be expired on logout ?

Thanks for your help and guidance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just set this cookie to be expired as a normal cookie by setting its expiry date to -1d.

Answer (score 1):

Why you need VerificationToken for the logout , its dont have any sense.. This is just protecting vs cross-site-scripting and fired all time when something changes in Cookie objects like FormAuthenticated values or some form data just it.

Comment: thanks.

User is redirected to login page once he log out and login page has Html.AntiForgeryToken() in it.

Any suggestion please how to set __RequestVerificationToken_Lw__   as expired and cleared from browser.